# Why put the constant before the variable in a comparison?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, comparison

I noticed for a while now the following syntax in some of our code:

```
if( NULL == var){
   //...
}
```

or

```
if( 0 == var){
  //...
}
```

and similar things.

Can someone please explain why did the person who wrote this choose this notation instead of the common `var == 0` way)?

Is it a matter of style, or does it somehow affect performance?

Comment: Lots of answers about the 'why' of the practice - for completeness, the practice has no effect on performance.

Comment: It depends on who's performance you are talking about, reading code backwards slows my performance :)

Comment: @Robert: Agreed - but I find myself still using it sometimes.  I'm embarrassed to say that every now again I get bit by the damn 'assignment hidden in a conditional' bug.

Comment: @MikeB: I make the mistake on occasion too which is why I keep the warnings turned up on the compiler, I've never been "bitten" by it because the compiler has always caught it.

Comment: Caveat: If `var` is of complex type (e.g. smart pointer) and implements `bool operator==(T *p) const` as well as `operator T*()`, this may have [side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168637/shared-pointer-constness-in-comparison-operator/49169757#49169757).

Comment: FYI, it is called [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's a mechanism to avoid mistakes like this:

```
if ( var = NULL ) {
  // ...
}
```

If you write it with the variable name on the right hand side the compiler will be able catch certain mistakes:

```
if ( NULL = var ) {  // not legal, won't compile
  // ...
}
```

Of course this won't work if variable names appear on both sides of the equal sign and some people find this style unappealing.

**Edit:**

As Evan mentioned in the comments, any decent compiler will warn you about this if you enable warnings, for example, `gcc -Wall` will give you the following:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

You should always enable warnings on your compiler, it is the cheapest way to find errors.

Lastly, as Mike B points out, this is a matter of style and doesn't affect the performance of the program.

Comment: Most compilers worth their salt will give you a warning for the first example.

Comment: Yep, as I just commented in the question my compiler has always caught this for me, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Not only should you enable warnings on the compiler - you should pay attention to them, and revise the code so that the warnings cease to appear.  Otherwise, you end up with builds with thousands of warnings...which are a complete pain.  (I work on one such - it infuriates me!)

Comment: And when I say 'revise the code', I don't just mean 'insert random casts until the warnings cease', which is a common misinterpretation of how to fix a lot of compiler warnings.

Answer (score 14):

If you mistakenly put

```
if ( var = NULL )
```

instead of

```
if ( var == NULL )
```

then there will only be a compiler warning.  If you reverse the order:

```
if ( NULL == var )
```

then there will be a compiler error if you put

```
if ( NULL = var )
```

Personally, I hate to read code written that way, and I only made that mistake once in my first year of coding. =)

Comment: This is why my students are required to compile with -Wall -Werror.  So I don't have to read the ugly stuff :-)

Comment: I saw this style in all over [PHP Symfony source-code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/24680199a8c3b7b3ffc2f0e50f96b77b62975b90/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Descriptor/Descriptor.php#L203). It's not only unappealing, it's just confusing. PHP has no compiler (at least not in the way C++ has) and I get the point out of it, but my humble opinion is that experienced developers that still need this just *worth* that bug. It's a hard to debug like uninitialized variables. They commit it first time, then no more. Anyway, readability first IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

**Corollary:** try to use `const` as much as you can.

```
const int val = 42;

if (val = 43) {
    ...
}
```

will not compile.

Comment: I'm all for using const wherever possible but you don't usually check the value of constant variables nearly as often as you do variables that actually change so I don't know how much this would really help.  The easiest way to avoid these kinds of errors is to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: another idea is to do if(+val = 43) and even if val is non-const, it still won't compile :)

Comment: @litb: That's an interesting idea but it will only work for arithmetic types (not pointers).

Comment: Robert, these are the darn diffs between C and C++ :/ in C++ +ptr is possible and yields an rvalue.

Comment: I didn't know about that difference between C and C++ - cheers :-)

Comment: @RobertGamble I guess it is true for constants (who compares constants?!). However, I very often define a variable within my functions once and I don't expect to ever change it, then I mark it `const`. That way I avoid many potential mistakes. i.e. I'd rather have 10 such `const` variables than reusing the same variable 10 times.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid the

```
if (var = NULL)
```

bug

Answer (score 5):

Quoting Joel On Software, [The Guerrilla Guide to Interviewing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000073.html):

> Occasionally, you will see a C programmer write something like if (0==strlen(x)), putting the constant on the left hand side of the == . This is a really good sign. It means that they were stung once too many times by confusing = and == and have forced themselves to learn a new habit to avoid that trap.

(I'm not really a fan of this "best practice".)

Comment: hehe, (0 == strlen(x)) is actually a bad sign, ('\0' == x[0]) would be good :)

Comment: *hehe, (0 == strlen(x)) is actually a bad sign, ('\0' == x[0]) would be good*  -1, smug.  `0 == strcmp(...)` is the same pattern, and there's no shortcut.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `'\0' == x[0]` is actually great if you can guarantee `x` is never `NULL`, which, in many cases, you can. It always runs in constant time while `strlen(x)` doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Note that `if (strlen(x) = 0)` would never have compiled, even when C was first created. So I guess that's an altogether bad example.

Comment: @cebola Note that `strlen()` does not verify the input parameter and if `NULL`, your program `SEGV`. So the `x[0]` will not be any different in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Just by the way, I've observed over many years teaching C to new programmers that if you train yourself to read "=" as "gets" and "==" as equals, that in itself will save you from a lot of these bugs. Then you read

```
if( x = 0){
```

as "if x gets 0 then" and that begins to sound weird.

Comment: That is a good idea only if you're never going to read any mathematics in your life again :p

Comment: If I'm being careful in explaining code to somebody else, I tend to use "is assigned" for =.

Comment: Shree, you do this all the time if you're moving from math to computers, and even in math.  Consider saying when we say T(n)=O(n) -- that "=" isn't an "equals", it's an abuse of the notation to say it is. Calling the "=" symbol "gets" just acknowledges this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer

`if (!x) {`

Comment: That works fine for checking against zero but not so much for any other value.

Comment: It's also just a little too easy to miss the ! when looking over someone elses code...