# How to use raw input with windows Xp

Tags: c#, .net, raw-input

I have try to use Raw Input from this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

I develop on **windows 7** `64 bit` with `.net 4.0` and **Visual Studio 2010**
it work perfectly in windows 7 but after I test the program on windows XP service pack 3 `32&64 bit`, it cannot register input device. It might be some mistake at this step for **Windows XP** but in **Windows 7** it work well.

```
    if(!Win32.RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0])))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to register raw input device(s).");
    }
```

in **Win32** import **User32.dll** like this

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool RegisterRawInputDevices(RawInputDevice[] pRawInputDevice, uint numberDevices, uint size);
```

**How can I make it work with windows XP.**

Comment: For starters, you could try reading the error message you get back.

Comment: I have try but the program wasn't error it just alway return false in this 'Win32.RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0]))' ,I am not sure about  imoort `User32.dll` it will work the same with **Windows XP**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1650868/2715716 Check what this returns.

Comment: I try by add like this 
   `if(!Win32.RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0])))
   {
                string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to register raw input device(s).");
   }`
but it alert only "Invalid flags"

Comment: I am wondering if you found a solution for that problem, I am facing same behavior on Win XP. Windows 7 and up works great. Thanks!