# How to get DirectDraw Last error string(DirectX 7)

Tags: c++, directx, directdraw

When I failed executing a DirectDraw method, how to get the failure error string in DirectX 7?

```
if (FAILED(lpddPrimarySurface->SetPalette(lpddPalette)))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, **"I want to get the failure string here."**, "Error", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I want to pop up the error messge of the failure information. How to get the LPCSTR string of the error?

Comment: You're setting a palette?  Are you trying to target 8-bit (256) color modes? That might not be supported on newer hardware.

Comment: Yeah, I always SetPalette failed. What should I use while I can't use 8-bit(256) color mode? Could you provide some details, thanks.

Comment: You never said what error code SetPalette is returning. It's entirely possible you palette object is mis-initialized. I was just commenting that it seems entirely odd to use an 8-bit display mode in 2013. I don't know of a single graphic card manufactured in the last 10 years that doesn't support 24-bit modes (and hence, no palette is needed).

Comment: @selbie: unless you want to do a palette rotation effect or some palette mappings in an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error string provided by DirectDraw. You have to look at the returned HRESULT and format your own string as needed.  For example:

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/8268-ddraw-error-code/

Answer (score 1):

For NTSTATUS errors the following is possible. Not sure if this will work for Direct Draw and Direct X HRESULT error codes, but it may do as they may be in the system message table. You don't need the ntdll handle either I don't think because the look up is done on the system message table. I have specified it just in case as I have never tested without it.

Excuse the static char array, this just to show example, not a good implementation :)

```
static const char *NTStatusToString(DWORD NtStatusCode)
{
    LPVOID lpMessageBuffer = 0;
    HMODULE hNTDll = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");
    static char szBuffer[256];

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE,
        hNTDll,
        NtStatusCode,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMessageBuffer,
        0,
        NULL);

    memset(szBuffer, 0, sizeof(szBuffer));
    _snprintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)-1, "%s", lpMessageBuffer);

    LocalFree(lpMessageBuffer);

    return szBuffer;
}
```

This thread suggests it will work [How should I use FormatMessage() properly in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455434/how-should-i-use-formatmessage-properly-in-c)  however this one suggests it won't [Is there a way to get the string representation of HRESULT value using win API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008047/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-string-representation-of-hresult-value-using-win-api) and you will have to do a bit more work than this.

Further reading: [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/10/1054354.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/03/942851.aspx) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256348/en-us)