# RegQueryValue fails but RegQueryValueEx returns a value

Tags: c, winapi, registry

I am attempting to play with some of the 16 and 32 bit registry functions, and I'm having trouble with using RegQueryValue (not extended). I am opening a handle to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\EventSystem (this key was chosen at random, the problem is persistent across keys). When I call RegQueryValue for "Configured", there is an error. However, for RegQueryValueEx, I am actually able to get the value.

I am running this on Windows 7 x64, tested with admin rights (Not having admin rights means RegOpenKeyEx fails with insufficient rights).

Here is the code (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455434/how-should-i-use-formatmessage-properly-in-c for printErrorMessage):

```
#define BUFLEN 80
int main() {
    HKEY hkey;
    DWORD ret = RegOpenKeyA(rootKey, "Software\\Microsoft\\EventSystem", &hkey);
    printf("Opened key, handle is %i\n", hkey);
    LONG buflen = BUFLEN;
    DWORD dwbuflen = BUFLEN;
    char data[BUFLEN];
    BYTE bdata[BUFLEN];
    ret = RegQueryValueA(hkey, "Configured", data, &buflen);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Unable to open Configured with RegQueryValueA\n");
        printErrorMessage(ret);
    } else {
        printf("Value of Configured was %s\n", data);
    }
    ret = RegQueryValueExA(hkey, "Configured", 0, NULL, bdata, &dwbuflen);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Unable to open Configured with RegQueryValueExA\n");
        printErrorMessage(ret);
    } else {
        printf("Value of Configured was %s\n", bdata);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Opened key, handle is 68
Unable to open Configured with RegQueryValueA
The system cannot find the file specified.
Value of Configured was ☺
```

(Configured's value is wonky because I am not yet bothering to convert from REG_DWORD to a string, but it is immaterial to the problem I am having).

Comment: Use RegOpenKeyEx. And check for errors on all your api calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `RegQueryValue(hkey, "Configured")`, that tries to read the *default value* (or *unnamed value*) of the *key* named "Configured". This is the semantics of [RegQueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() as described by MSDN.

So RegQueryValue() cannot be used to read named values like "Configured", so you must use [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() if you want to read a named value.

Answer (score 1):

You're querying a value, but the string parameter for `RegQueryValue()` is a **subkey**. See msdn for [`RegQueryValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) vs. [`RegQueryValueEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%5C).

Comment: I chose Xargs' answer because it was more descriptive, but you're also right. Thanks