# RegOpenKeyEx - what does error code 7 mean?

Tags: c, winapi, error-code

I am trying to code simple program in C which writes and reads something from Windows registry. What does the return value of 7 for `RegOpenKeyEx` mean?

I am having a hard time trying to guess it. Yes, MSDN says I can use FormatMessage to examine it, but it takes 7 arguments and I have no idea how to use it... (what an awful api design by the way).

Comment: Yes, that's a badly designed API. The system error codes are documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Btw, does it really return 7?

Comment: MSDN also says "If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h", which you can get a description from [MSDN - System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you really are getting 7, this corresponds to `ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED`.

Comment: `ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED` is rather implausible. MCVE please.

Comment: Most error codes can be checked using `net helpmsg`, e.g., `net helpmsg 7`

Comment: Another helpful way to turn error messages into human readable form is to use the debugger. Type `7,hr` into the watch window and it will display its string representation. Not applicable here, but the return value of `GetLastError` is supported by the pseudo-variable `@err`. So if you type `@err,hr` into the watch window, you have a convenient way to analyze errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN entry for `RegOpenKeyEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also indicates that:

> If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h.

Those error codes are documented in [MSDN - System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page. If you really are getting 7, then this error would correspond to:

> **ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED**
>       7 (0x7)
>       The storage control blocks were destroyed.

What it means could range from your registry being corrupted, to a slew of program errors resulting in seemingly weird behavior, or to simply that you are getting something else as a return value and are lead to believe you are getting a result of 7. Without a more complete code example, it is hard to venture anything more specific.

*P.S.*: `FormatMessage` is mostly handy if you are trying to obtain a string representation of the error at run time. If that's the case, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455533/2994596) for an example on how to use it.