# Why does FormatMessage only create partial messages for ERROR_SYSTEM_PROCESS_TERMINATED and ERROR_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION system errors?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++-2015, formatmessage

I have been using the FormatMessage function within the Windows API to generate message strings from system error codes.  I noticed that for some error codes the full message doesn't appear to be created.

Take this sample program as an example:

```
int main()
{
  wchar_t * buffer = nullptr;
  FormatMessageW(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM 
    | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER 
    | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
    nullptr, 
    ERROR_SYSTEM_PROCESS_TERMINATED,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&buffer), 
    0, 
    nullptr);

  std::wcout << buffer << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388(v=vs.85).aspx) I should see the following:

> {Fatal System Error}
>   The %hs system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0x%08x (0x%08x 0x%08x). The system has been shut down.

However, in the sample program I will see:

> {Fatal System Error}
>   The %hs system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0x

I noticed that `ERROR_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` also doesn't create the full message (when compared to the list on MSDN).  Both of the expected messages contain **0x%08** placeholders, but the message ends after **0x**.

From what I can see, other error messages appear to match the lists on MSDN (i.e. the issue appears to be restricted to `ERROR_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` and `ERROR_SYSTEM_PROCESS_TERMINATED`).

---

Credit to engf-010 - you get the same if you use the Error Lookup tool in Visual Studio (Tools - Error Lookup).  The error codes are 574 and 591.

---

Does anyone know why these messages are being cropped?

Is there anyway to get the full message?

Comment: You should always check the return value of system calls ! It may shine some light on your issue.

Comment: @engf-010 - If I set the last error as 0 before `FormatMessageW`, `GetLastError()` immediately after `FormatMessageW` shows as 0.

Comment: As a side note, you should `LocalFree`/`HeapFree` the buffer returned when using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`. Even though that might not be relevant in this small example.

Comment: Not using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` for arbitrary system error codes is a bug (as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx)). Please include it in your code (and not just mention it further down).

Comment: @Christian.K - yes, this is in the production code.

Comment: Somewhat reassuring : the Error Lookup utility gives the same error description ,so if MS can't do it right ...

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages you mention (`ERROR_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` and `ERROR_SYSTEM_PROCESS_TERMINATED`) have printf-style inserts (`%08x`).  However, FormatMessage uses %0 to terminate a message.

My guess is that there's another avenue where these messages are returned by the system with the printf-style placeholders already populated; these messages, in their raw form, are not meant to be handled by FormatMessage.

Given that these messages contain the text `(Fatal System Error)` or `(Application Error)`, it is not altogether surprising that Windows handles these message specially.

Comment: I'm totally more inclined to believe, that the return value of [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) shouldn't be flushed down the drains...

Comment: *"Given that these are fatal system errors"* - No, they aren't. They are (potentially) fatal process errors. Nothing the system is terribly concerned about. The kernel destroys the process objects, and moves on. This happens all the time.

Comment: @IInspectable I've updated the answer to indicate this terminology (Fatal System Error) comes from the text of the error message.

Comment: I can't say for certain, but it seems that the issue is an oversight/limitation in the API.  It goes against the recommended approach for retrieving system error messages.  The only workaround I can see is to do a check on the error code before formatting, and then branch off to create the expected messages for the 2 scenarios I have found.

Comment: If I understand these error codes, you won't be seeing them in your app.

Comment: @jdigital: `ERROR_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` is likely to show up in an unhandled exception filter (see [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634.aspx)), so it can occur in your process.

Comment: @IInspectable: can you expand on that?  I don't see how it would happen.