# Shared pointer constness in comparison operator ==

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr, comparison-operators

I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior of a shared pointer I'm using.

The shared pointer implements reference counting and *detaches* (e.g. makes a copy of), if neccessary, the contained instance on non-const usage.
To achieve this, for each getter function the smart pointer has a `const` and a `non-const` version, for example: `operator T *()` and `operator T const *() const`.

**Problem:** Comparing the pointer value to `nullptr` leads to a detach.

**Expected:** I thought that the comparison operator would always invoke the const version.

Simplified example:
(This implementation doesn't have reference counting, but still shows the problem)

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class SharedPointer
{
public:
    inline operator T *() { std::cout << "Detached"; return d; }
    inline operator const T *() const { std::cout << "Not detached"; return d; }
    inline T *data() { std::cout << "Detached"; return d; }
    inline const T *data() const { std::cout << "Not detached"; return d; }
    inline const T *constData() const { std::cout << "Not detached"; return d; }

    SharedPointer(T *_d) : d(_d) { }

private:
    T *d;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SharedPointer<int> testInst(new int(0));

    bool eq;

    std::cout << "nullptr  == testInst: ";
    eq = nullptr == testInst;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // Output: nullptr  == testInst: Detached

    std::cout << "nullptr  == testInst.data(): ";
    eq = nullptr == testInst.data();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // Output: nullptr  == testInst.data(): Detached

    std::cout << "nullptr  == testInst.constData(): ";
    eq = nullptr == testInst.constData();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // Output: nullptr  == testInst.constData(): Not detached
}
```

**Question 1:** Why is the non-const version of the functions called when it *should* be sufficient to call the const version?

**Question 2:** Why *can* the non-const version be called anyways? Doesn't the comparison operator (especially comparing to the immutable `nullptr`) always operate on const references?

---

For the record:
The shared pointer I'm using is Qt's `QSharedDataPointer` holding a `QSharedData`-derived instance, but this question is not Qt-specific.

---

**Edit:**

In my understanding, `nullptr == testInst` would invoke

```
bool operator==(T const* a, T const* b)
```

(Because why should I *compare* non-const pointers?)

which should invoke:

```
inline operator const T *() const
```

**Further questions:**

- Why isn't it the default to use the const operator?

  - Is this because a function cannot be selected by the type of the return value alone?
    => This is answered in [Calling a const function rather than its non-const version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287065/calling-a-const-function-rather-than-its-non-const-version?rq=1)

**So this question boils down to:**

- Why doesn't the default implementation of the comparison operator take the arguments as const refs and then call the const functions?
- Can you maybe cite a c++ reference?

Comment: Look at what `std::vector::operator[]` does.

Comment: `testInst` needs to be cast into a pointer. Since `testInst` is a non-const object, its non-const cast operator is naturally selected.

Comment: @DanielLangr It's the *naturally* that confuses me. See the edit for detailed questions.

Comment: why do you assume that the `==` chosen is `bool operator==(T const* a, T const* b)` and not `bool operator==(T * a, T * b)`?

Comment: @MartinHennings Even if you needed to cast `testInst` into a const pointer, still `testInst` would be a non-const object. This is what matters when const/non-const member function/operator overloads are resolved.

Comment: @MartinHennings Look here for live example to (hopefully) understand what happens: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rAvIHMAhSeao5tUl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there exists an overload on const and non-const, the compiler will always call non-const version if the object you're using is non-const. Otherwise, when would the non-const version *ever* be invoked?

If you want to explicitly use the const versions, invoke them through a const reference:

```
const SharedPointer<int>& constRef = testInst;
eq = nullptr == constRef;
```

In the context of Qt's `QSharedDataPointer`, you can also use the `constData` function explicitly whenever you need a pointer.

For the intended usage of `QSharedDataPointer`, this behavior is not usually a problem. It is meant to be a member of a facade class, and thus used only from its member functions. Those member functions that don't need modification (and thus don't need detaching) are expected to be `const` themselves, making the member access to the pointer be in a `const` context and thus not detach.

#### Edit to answer the edit:

> In my understanding, nullptr == testInst would invoke
>
> ```
> bool operator==(T const* a, T const* b)
> ```

This understanding is incorrect. Overload resolutions for operators is rather complex, with a big set of proxy signatures for the built-in version of the operator taking part in the resolution. This process is described in [over.match.oper] and [over.built] in the standard.

Specifically, the relevant built-in candidates for equality are defined in [over.built]p16 and 17. These rules say that for *every* pointer type `T`, an `operator ==(T, T)` exists. Now, both `int*` and `const int*` are pointer types, so the two relevant signatures are `operator ==(int*, int*)` and `operator ==(const int*, const int*)`. (There's also `operator ==(std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t)`, but it won't be selected.)

To distinguish between the two overloads, the compiler has to compare conversion sequences. For the first argument, `nullptr_t -> int*` and `nullptr_t -> const int*` are both identical; they are pointer conversions. Adding the `const` to one of the pointers is subsumed. (See [conv.ptr].) For the second argument, the conversions are `SharedPointer<int> -> int*` and `SharedPointer<int> -> const int*`, respectively. The first of these is a user-defined conversion, invoking `operator int*()`, with no further conversions necessary. The second is a user-defined conversion, invoking `operator const int*() const`, which necessitates a qualification conversion first in order to call the `const` version. Therefore, the non-const version is preferred.

Comment: I stumbled upon this inside a member function which copies the shared pointer (thus non-const function) only if it differs from the previous value. The diff already lead to a detach.

Comment: I understand now why the non-const version is used. I edited my question, can you perhaps extend your answer regarding constness in the comparison operator?

Comment: @MartinHennings Done.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how the expression `testInst == nullptr` is resolved:

1. Let's look at the types:
   `testInst` is of type `SharedPointer<int>`.
   `nullptr` is (for the sake of simplification) of type `T*` or `void*`, depending on the use case.
   So the expression reads `SharedPointer<int> == int*`.
2. We need to have equal types to invoke a comparison operator. There are two possibilities:

   1. Resolve to `int* == int*`.
      This involves a call to `operator int *()` or `operator int const *() const`.
      [citation needed]
   2. Resolve to `SharedPointer<int> == SharedPointer<int>`
      This involves a call to `SharedPointer(nullptr)`.
3. Because the second option would create a new object, and the first one doesn't, the first option is the better match. [citation needed]
4. Now *before* resolving `bool operator==(int [const] *a, int [const] *b)` (the `[const]` is irrelevant), `testInst` must be converted to `int*`.
   This involves a call to the conversion `operator int *()` or `operator int const *() const`.
   Here, the *non-const version* will be called because `testInst` is not const. [citation needed]

---

I created a suggestion to add comparison operators for `T*` to `QSharedDataPointer<T>` at Qt Bugs: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66946

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will allow you to understand what happens:

```
class X {
   public:
      operator int * () { std::cout << "1\n"; return nullptr; }
      operator const int * () { std::cout << "2\n"; return nullptr; }
      operator int * () const { std::cout << "3\n"; return nullptr; }
      operator const int * () const { std::cout << "4\n"; return nullptr; }
};

int main() {
   X x;
   const X & rcx = x;

   int* pi1 = x;
   const int* pi2 = x;
   int* pi3 = rcx;
   const int* pi4 = rcx;
}
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
4
```

If the const object (or reference to it) is casted, the `const` cast operator (case 3 and 4) is choosen, and vice versa.